# Dota 2 keep items from being crafted?

Tags: dota-2

When I buy items that can be crafted, they are crafted immediately.  Sometimes they are crafted too soon, into things I don't actually want.  For example, I sometimes end up with power treads or a ring of basilius when I'm really building toward something else.

Is there a way to stop your guy from crafting items automatically?  Or do you just need to buy your items in a different order?

Comment: What the hell are you building when you accidently end up having PowerTreads? PT's are always the best choice if you really need that items :). Why should you need gloves of attack but not for boots? Midas? why need belt of strengh or similar first?

Comment: My builds are my own :)  RayofCommand may be right, but I think it should be possible to have the parts without building power treads.

Comment: :) of course they are. just be careful not to build tranquil boots, since you cant change them later on

Answer (score 3):

You have to pay attention in what order you build your items in order to don't built something you don't want. However be aware that some items can be [disassembled](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131259/can-you-disassemble-items) when you have built them by mistake

Answer (score 0):

There's two choices, either build your items in a different order, or disassemble it by right clicking on the item and clicking "disassemble"

Comment: Only certain items can be disassebled though